# Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning: Maximizing log likelihood with respect to Beta

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, pattern-recognition, log-likelihood

On page 29 in Christopher Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning book he gives the following two equations

1.62

$$ 
\ln p(t|\pmb{x}, \pmb{w}, \beta) = - \frac{\beta}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N 
\{ y(x_n, \pmb{w}) - t_n \}^2 + \frac{N}{2} \ln \beta - \frac{N}{2} \ln(2\pi) 
$$

He then goes on to explain that maximizing this with respect to w would result in the following by basically removing everything that is not dependent on $w$ which makes sense...

$$ 
\pmb{w}_{ML} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \{ y(x_n, w) - t_n \}^2 
$$

Immediately following this the claim is made that maximizing with respect to $\beta$ gives the following...

$$
\frac{1}{\beta_{ML}} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{m=1}^N \{ y(x_n, w) - t_n \}^2
$$

and I can't quite get there by the same logic, how would you arrive at this?

Comment: Did you try differentiating the log-likelihood with respect to $\beta$ and setting the derivative to $0$?

Comment: I think I was wrongly putting a term in the summand which was screwing me up. I believe my answer arrives there correctly. Does it look right @MinusOne-Twelfth ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrongly assuming that the $\frac{N}{2} \ln \beta$ was part of the summand. Taking the derivative and setting it to 0 gave me the proper outcome.

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \Big\lbrack -\frac{\beta}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N 
\{ y(x_n, \pmb{w}) - t_n \}^2 + \frac{N}{2} \ln \beta - \frac{N}{2} \ln(2\pi) \Big\rbrack \\
&\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \Big\lbrack -\frac{\beta}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N 
\{ y(x_n, \pmb{w}) - t_n \}^2 \Big\rbrack + \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \Big\lbrack \frac{N}{2} \ln \beta \Big\rbrack \\
0 = &-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N 
\{ y(x_n, \pmb{w}) - t_n \}^2 + \frac{N}{2\beta}\\
-\frac{N}{2\beta} = &-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N 
\{ y(x_n, \pmb{w}) - t_n \}^2 \\
\frac{1}{2\beta} = &\frac{1}{2N} \sum_{n=1}^N 
\{ y(x_n, \pmb{w}) - t_n \}^2 \\
\frac{1}{\beta} = &\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N 
\{ y(x_n, \pmb{w}) - t_n \}^2 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Yes, that ks correct